# Azure VM is showing connection timeout

Tags: azure, couchdb, virtual-machine

I'm pretty new to Windows Azure.

I created a couchDB VM on my Azure account but whenever I try to connect it throguh DNS. I get connection timeout.

here is the screen shot of settings. I really don't understand where should I go from here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that SSH endpoint is open? Go to settings --> Endpoints and add port 22 if it is not in the list

Comment: Port 22 is already in the list and its open to public as well

Comment: were you ever able to connect to the VM? Try to reset the remote access to the VM ("Reset remote access" in the portal)